# React Hook UseEffect create duplicate objects in setState

Tags: reactjs, axios, use-effect

I got a problem with a component. I make a n number calls to an external API and then get back values inside an object. I want to add each of this object return in the state. However, each object is duplicate in my state. I try to put conditions but nothing work. I just started with React and Node so I'm sorry if the solution is obvious...

```
    //Id for the API calls
    const Ref = ['268', '294']
 
    const nbreLiens = Ref.length
    
    //For each Id we make an API call, get the response, and set the state without erasing the previous value
    Ref.map(lien=>{

      const Tok = localStorage.getItem('token');

      Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/liens/sup/"+Tok+"/"+lien).then((Response) => {
        
        //We shouldn't get more entries that the number of Id's
        if (test.length<nbreLiens){
          setTest(test=>[...test,Response.data])
        }
      })
    })

  }, [])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try resolving all the API call Promises first, then add the resposes to the state.

(Im not handling errors)

```
//Id for the API calls
const Ref = ['268', '294']

useEffect(() => {
    const getElements = async (idsToGet) => {
        const Tok = localStorage.getItem('token');
        const allPromises = idsToGet.map(id => Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/liens/sup/" + Tok + "/" + id))
        const dataElements = await Promise.all(allPromises)
        const responseDataElements = dataElements.map(response => response.data)
        setTest(() => responseDataElements)
    }
    getElements(Ref);
}, [])
```

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you so much. I just started React and I think I should read about the javascript concepts await, promise async that is still a little bit obscure. Anyway you've been very helpful thanks

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that your statement `if (test.length<nbreLiens){` will not work as you are expecting.

In resume: `test.length` will always be the same even after calling `setTest` inside this function.

From react docs:

> In React, both this.props and this.state represent the rendered
> values, i.e. what’s currently on the screen.
>
> Calls to setState are asynchronous - don’t rely on this.state to
> reflect the new value immediately after calling setState. Pass an
> updater function instead of an object if you need to compute values
> based on the current state (see below for details).

You can read more about this at: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html

Comment: Thank you, I didn't see that it was asynchronous. It really helps